# Libgdx Scene2d: Event Listener on Table

Tags: java, libgdx, event-listener, scene2d

I wanted to know how you can detect a touch event on a table. Although I have tried using inputlistener. But it only gives me touch on the elements. But instead i want touch to be detected everywhere on the table. In short I want my table to be turned as Button.

Comment: You should always add Java as a tag if you expect java code to be supplied so code highlighting for java works.

Answer (score 10):

You can add a listener to any actor on your stage. In your case I would suggest a `ClickListener`. You can add the ClickListener as a "anonymous class" like I did below. Override it's `clicked` method with your logic you can get rid of the call to `.super` as the base method does nothing. You have access to specific details in the `InputEvent` that is supplied such as which button is pressed.

```
    Table table = new Table();
    //Might just be this line to have the table interact.
    table.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled); 
    t.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            System.out.println("I got clicked!");
        }
    });
```

Of course your table needs to be expanded in order to click it. If you are not able to click it you should run `table.debug()` and make sure you see the table bounds on your screen and click within these.

Comment: Thanks again!! I did exactly the same. Actually I figured out that you have to set a boolean but the new problem is that this particular table is in a split pane. And when i scroll the pane the touch gets activated. So now lemme find solution for that.

Comment: Instead of `clicked` you can try overriding @touchUp inside the `Listener`. But this might fire  the table click when you release inside it. So what you could do is whenever you are dragging you remove the listener from the table. First `table.getListeners` and then iterate over these listeners and remove them from your table. But you have to add them again when you stop scrolling.

Comment: sorry the table is in scroll pane

Comment: although I haven't tried this method but I will get back to you if i find it successful or not